# Html and CSS image uploader

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to convert this image bubble(Below), so i can use it to upload my images when the user creates the account, for example when the user hovers of the image bubble it will display an "Upload profile image" and when the user clicks it, it should prompt them to upload an image. Can anyone push me in the right direction to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You must have tried something...Please show us ...we will guide you thereafter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know how image uploading works, if not, please do specify.
In css, have you tried:

```
form{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    /* You'll need to fine-tune this part */
    top: 50px;
    left:50px;
    /* If you want, you can add a transition on opacity */
}

form:hover{
    opacity:1
}
```